# Listview Footer in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, footer

I want apply the footer below the list view. The footer is a `textview`, When list is empty it show the footer, but data searchable then below the list footer is not shown, help me, It is linear layout for android.

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add textview where you want with this attribute

> visibility:gone

and in your activity when you do get any data from your search then

> text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

but if your search returns any data then set

> visibility as visible to textview
>
> text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);